# don't set value to field of \Magento\Framework\Data\Form

Tags: module, magento2, forms

i try set value to custom file

```
$fieldset->addField('custom_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'custom_id', 'value' => '112' ]);
```

in frontend input it not value. what wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try set value for fields at end of the function:

```
$data = $model->getData();
$data['custom_id'] = 112;
$form->setValues($data);
$this->setForm($form);

return parent::_prepareForm();
```